# Ext.Grid editing with max length validation

Tags: validation, extjs, extjs4, maxlength, max-size

I have a Ext.grid.Panel with Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing plugin.

It's working fine, but I need to limit the size of 2 string fields to avoid insert/update exceptions coming from DB.

I have tried maxLength property in Grid column and `validations: [ {type: 'length', field: 'no_fornecedor', max: 49} ]` in the Ext.data.Model. But none worked, ExtJS still lets user type as many text as he wants and update with no warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!

In the column we must add the following `editor` property:

```
{
    header: 'name',
    dataIndex: 'id',
    flex: 1,
    editor: {
        allowBlank: false,
        maxLength: 49
    }
}
```